# Yeoman error after clicking download button on new node serverless app

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have created a a new node serverless app (the lite one), created a DB in the associated cloudant service and clicked the download code button.

It spun for a while and then I got the following error

```
[SCAFF] Yeo generation failed due to error in generating a generator.
```

Anyone got a hint on how to debug/resolve please?

I'm just following the Knowledge guide to get familiar with the tooling.

Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried and worked.

I navigated to https://cloud.ibm.com/developer/appservice/apps and created a NodeJS + Cloudant serverless app in **Washington DC** region and I am able to download the code.

Alternatively, You can also download the app code from the CLI using the following command

```
ibmcloud dev code <APPLICATION_NAME>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just retried this morning with same app and Download is working fine. Gremlins 8-)